# Running grass7:r.watershed in QGIS gives different results to running identical process in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, grass-gis, flow-direction, topographic-wetness-index

a former colleague created a QGIS tool in Python for the Team which creates Flow Routes and TWI (Topographic Wetness Indicator) maps for a selected location.

I have run through the code and copied the method to the letter within QGIS using:

**

- 'reprojector'
- 'r.fill.dir'
  -'r.watershed'
  **

But I get different results that I cannot match to the python tool output!! Initially the output looks correct but the value of each pixel is different. These are the 2 outputs from the QGIS tool created with python code:
[image]

This is what I get for the TWI when I follow it in QGIS processing toolbox.
[image]

Code relating to the TWI and Flow Routes that I have followed along with in QGIS, making sure I copy all the settings listed and use the correct elevation surface model  .asc file as a base.

#if there is only 1 layer, store it in a dictionary so that the ouput matches the format returned by the merge alg which is run above when there is more than 1 layer
dsmStr = dsmPathLst[0].replace(".TAB", ".asc")
dsmDict = {'OUTPUT': dsmStr}

```
    dsm = core.QgsRasterLayer(dsmDict['OUTPUT'])
    bng = core.QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(
        27700,
        core.QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId
    )
    dsm.setCrs(bng)

    #fill sinks in the dsm to allow proper hydrological modelling
    ''' extent = dsm.extent()
    xmin = extent.xMinimum()
    xmax = extent.xMaximum()
    ymin = extent.yMinimum()
    ymax = extent.yMaximum()'''
    
    tempFill = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    tempDirection = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    tempAreas = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    
    fillParameters = {
        'input' : dsm,
        'format' : 0, #0=grass
        'f' : False, #Find unresolved areas only
        'output' : tempFill.name + '.tif',
        'direction' : tempDirection.name + '.tif',
        'areas' : tempAreas.name + '.tif',
        'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER': dsm, #use the extent of the input
        'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER' : 2 #2m matches the LiDAR data used
    }

    filledDsmResults = processing.run("grass7:r.fill.dir", fillParameters)
    filledDsm = core.QgsRasterLayer(filledDsmResults['output'])
    
    tempAccumulation = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    tempDrainage = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    tempBasin = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    tempStream = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    tempHalfBasin = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    tempLengthSlope = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    tempSlopeSteepness = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    tempTci = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    tempSpi = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    
    #calc hydrology layers
    watershedParams = {
        'elevation' : filledDsm,
        #'depression' : None,
        #'flow' : None,
        #'disturbed_land' : None,
        #'blocking' : None,
        'threshold' : 10,
        'max_slope_length' : 0,
        'convergence' : 5,
        'memory' : 300,
        's' : False,
        'm' : False,
        '4' : False,
        'a' : False,
        'b' : True,
        'accumulation' : tempAccumulation.name + '.tif',
        'drainage' : tempDrainage.name + '.tif',
        'basin' : tempBasin.name + '.tif',
        'stream' : tempStream.name + '.tif',
        'half_basin' : tempHalfBasin.name + '.tif',
        'length_slope' : tempLengthSlope.name + '.tif',
        'slope_steepness' : tempSlopeSteepness.name + '.tif',
        'tci' : tempTci.name + '.tif',
        'spi' : tempSpi.name + '.tif',
        'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : dsm,
        'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER' : 2,
        #'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT' : None,
        #'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META' : None,
    }

    #run rWatershed from grass
    hydroLyrs = processing.run("grass7:r.watershed", watershedParams)
        
    #make flow routes rmap
    streamLyr = core.QgsRasterLayer(hydroLyrs['accumulation'])
    stats = streamLyr.dataProvider().bandStatistics(1, core.QgsRasterBandStats.All)
    midCat = stats.maximumValue/400

    #list of colour and value intervals to pass to the styleRaster function
    lst = [
        core.QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(
            stats.minimumValue,
            QColor("#000000"),
            str(stats.minimumValue)
        ),
        core.QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(
            0, 
            QColor("#f7fbff"),
            '0'
        ),
        core.QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(
            midCat,
            QColor("#08306b"),
            str(midCat)
        )
    ]
        
    self.styleRaster(streamLyr, lst)
    self.makeMap(
        inPoint, 
        self.foi, 
        [baseMapLines,
            baseMapText,
            streamLyr
        ],
        [],
        "Flow Routes",
    )

    #make wetness index map
    tciLyr = core.QgsRasterLayer(hydroLyrs['tci'])
    tciLyr.setName("TWI")

    #list of colour and value intervals to pass to the styleRaster function
    lst = [core.QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(0, QColor("#f7fbff"),'0'),
        core.QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(4, QColor("#deebf7"),'4'),
        core.QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(8, QColor("#c6dbef"),'8'),
        core.QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(12, QColor("#9ecae1"),'12'),
        core.QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(16, QColor("#6baed6"),'16'),
        core.QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(20, QColor("#4292c6"),'20'),
        core.QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(24, QColor("#2171b5"),'24'),
        core.QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(28, QColor("#08519c"),'28'),
        core.QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(32, QColor("#08306b"),'32')
    ]

    self.styleRaster(tciLyr, lst)
    self.makeMap(inPoint,
        self.foi,
        [baseMapLines,
            baseMapText,
            tciLyr
        ], 
        [tciLyr],
        "Wetness Index",
    )
```